# How to integrate SQLAlchemy and a subclassed Numpy.ndarray smoothly and in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, numpy, sqlalchemy

I would like to store NumPy arrays with annotations (like `name`) via SQLAlchemy within a relational database. To do so,

- I separate the NumPy array from its data via a data transfer object (`DTONumpy` as part of `MyNumpy`).
- NumPy objects are collected with `Container`.

What would be a nice and pythonic way to modify `Container` (from the example below) in a way that it provides as a list directly `MyNumpy` objects instead of `DTONumpy` which is provided by SQLAlchemy?

Here is an illustration of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import zlib

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, CHAR

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Base = declarative_base()

#### New SQLAlchemy-Type #####################
class NumpyType (sa.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = sa.types.LargeBinary

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return zlib.compress(value.dumps(), 9)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return np.loads(zlib.decompress(value))
##############################################


class DTONumpy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dtos_numpy'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = sa.Column('amount', NumpyType)
    name = sa.Column('name', sa.String, default='')
    container_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey('containers.id'))

    container_object = relationship(
        "Container",
        uselist=False,
        backref='dto_numpy_objects'
        )

    def __init__(self, amount, name=None):
        self.amount = np.array(amount)
        self.name = name


class Container(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'containers'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String, unique=True)

    # HERE: how to access DTONumpy BUT as MyNumpy objects in a way that MyNumpy
    # is smoothly integrated into SQLAlchemy?


class MyNumpy(np.ndarray):
    _DTO = DTONumpy
    def __new__(cls, amount, name=''):
        dto = cls._DTO(amount=amount, name=name)
        return cls.newByDTO(dto)

    @classmethod
    def newByDTO(cls, dto):
        obj = np.array(dto.amount).view(cls)
        obj.setflags(write=False) # Immutable
        obj._dto = dto
        return obj

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._dto.name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = DBSession()

    mn1 = MyNumpy ([1,2,3], "good data")
    mn2 = MyNumpy ([2,3,4], "bad data")

    # Save MyNumpy objects
    c1 = Container()
    c1.name = "Test-Container"
    c1.dto_numpy_objects += [mn1._dto, mn2._dto] # not a good ui
    session.add(c1)
    session.commit()

    # Load MyNumpy objects
    c2 = session.query(Container).filter_by(name="Test-Container").first()
    # Ugly UI:
    mn3 = MyNumpy.newByDTO(c2.dto_numpy_objects[0])
    mn4 = MyNumpy.newByDTO(c2.dto_numpy_objects[1])
    name3 = mn3._dto.name
    name4 = mn4._dto.name
```

`Container` should now provide a list of `MyNumpy` objects and `MyNumpy` a reference to the according `Container` object (the list and the reference would have to take the SQLAlchemy mapping into account):

```
type (c2.my_numpy_objects[0]) == MyNumpy
>>> True
c2.my_numpy_objects.append(MyNumpy ([7,2,5,6], "new data")
print c2.dto_numpy_objects[-1].name
>>> "new data"
```

Comment: Have you considered [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin)? I've found that relational databases can be troublesome when working with n-dimensional arrays.

Comment: With pytable Francesc provides an awesome package on top of the hdf5 library, and I totally agree that this is in general the preferable solution to work with hierarchy organized numerical data! But the illustrated problem is an examplyfied data structure more compler one which is part a project that requires a relational database as a backend.

Comment: One way to go would probably be to implement a ListView that converts the types. For that see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984692/how-can-i-change-in-python-the-return-input-type-of-a-list-that-is-implemented-a).

Comment: A slightly unrelated question: Is zlib.(de-)compress really worth it?

Answer (score 6):

Using the `ListView`-answer from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984692/how-can-i-change-in-python-the-return-input-type-of-a-list-that-is-implemented-a/) question, I came up with the following solution:

First, modify `Container` by adding a `ListView`-property on top of the SQLAlchemy-property `dto_numpy_objects`:

```
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    """
    At this point, the following code doesn't work:
    ---------------------
    self.my_numpies = ListView(
        self.dto_numpy_objects, # see `DTO_Numpy.container_object`
        MyNumpy.newByDTO,
        MyNumpy.getDTO)
    ---------------------
    SQLAlchemy seems to change the `dto_numypy_object`-object after the
    init-call. Thus, `my_numpies._data` doesn't reference `dto_numpy_objects`
    anymore. One solution is to implement a property that initalizes `ListView`
    on first access. See below, property `Container.my_numpies`.
    """

  @property
  def my_numpies(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_my_numpies'):
      # The following part can not be exe
      self._my_numpies = ListView(
          self.dto_numpy_objects, # see `DTO_Numpy.container_object`
          MyNumpy.newByDTO,
          MyNumpy.getDTO)

    return self._my_numpies
```

Second, add method `getDTO` which can be used as `new2raw`-*converter* `MyNumpy`:

```
  def getDTO(self):
    return self._dto
```

In order to use the *backref* `container_object` also from `MyNumpy` implement it as a wrapper by adding the following method:

```
  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return getattr(self._dto, attr)
```

All together, the code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import zlib

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, CHAR

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Base = declarative_base()


class ListView(list):
  def __init__(self, raw_list, raw2new, new2raw):
    self._data = raw_list
    self.converters = {'raw2new': raw2new,
        'new2raw': new2raw}

  def __repr__(self):
    repr_list = [self.converters['raw2new'](item) for item in self._data]
    repr_str = "["
    for element in repr_list:
      repr_str += element.__repr__() + ",\n "
    repr_str = repr_str[:-3] + "]"
    return repr_str

  def append(self, item):
    self._data.append(self.converters['new2raw'](item))

  def pop(self, index):
    self._data.pop(index)

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.converters['raw2new'](self._data[index])

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self._data.__setitem__(key, self.converters['new2raw'](value))

  def __delitem__(self, key):
    return self._data.__delitem__(key)

  def __getslice__(self, i, j):
    return ListView(self._data.__getslice__(i,j), **self.converters)

  def __contains__(self, item):
    return self._data.__contains__(self.converters['new2raw'](item))

  def __add__(self, other_list_view):
    assert self.converters == other_list_view.converters
    return ListView(
        self._data + other_list_view._data,
        **self.converters)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self._data)

  def __iter__(self):
    return iter([self.converters['raw2new'](item) for item in self._data])

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self._data == other._data


#### New SQLAlchemy-Type #####################
class NumpyType (sa.types.TypeDecorator):
  impl = sa.types.LargeBinary

  def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
    return zlib.compress(value.dumps(), 9)

  def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
    return np.loads(zlib.decompress(value))
##############################################


class DTONumpy(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'dtos_numpy'
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  amount = sa.Column('amount', NumpyType)
  name = sa.Column('name', sa.String, default='')
  container_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey('containers.id'))

  container_object = relationship(
      "Container",
      uselist=False,
      backref='dto_numpy_objects'
      )

  def __init__(self, amount, name=None):
    self.amount = np.array(amount)
    self.name = name

  def reprInitParams(self):
    return "(%r, %r)" %(self.amount, self.name)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s%s" %(
        self.__class__.__name__,
        self.reprInitParams())


class Container(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'containers'
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = sa.Column(sa.String, unique=True)

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    super(Container, self).__init__()

  @property
  def my_numpies(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_my_numpies'):
      # The following part can not be exe
      self._my_numpies = ListView(
          self.dto_numpy_objects, # see `DTO_Numpy.container_object`
          MyNumpy.newByDTO,
          MyNumpy.getDTO)

    return self._my_numpies


class MyNumpy(np.ndarray):
  _DTO = DTONumpy
  def __new__(cls, amount, name=''):
    dto = cls._DTO(amount=amount, name=name)
    return cls.newByDTO(dto)

  @classmethod
  def newByDTO(cls, dto):
    obj = np.array(dto.amount).view(cls)
    obj.setflags(write=False) # Immutable
    obj._dto = dto
    return obj

  @property
  def name(self):
    return self._dto.name

  def getDTO(self):
    return self._dto

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return getattr(self._dto, attr)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s%s" %(
        self.__class__.__name__,
        self._dto.reprInitParams())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
  DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
  Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  session = DBSession()

  mn1 = MyNumpy ([1,2,3], "good data")
  mn2 = MyNumpy ([2,3,4], "bad data")

  # Save MyNumpy-Objects
  c1 = Container("Test-Container")
  c1.my_numpies.append(mn1)
  c1.my_numpies.append(mn2)
  session.add(c1)
  session.commit()

  # Load MyNumpy-Objects
  c2 = session.query(Container).filter_by(name="Test-Container").first()
  mn3 = c1.my_numpies[0]
  mn4 = c1.my_numpies[1]
```

For better representation I added

- `DTONumpy.reprInitParams`
- `DTONumpy.__repr__`
- `MyNumpy.__repr__`

One thing that still doesn't work:

```
  c1.my_numpies += [mn1, mn2.dto]
```