# What's the most appropriate way to insert and query a numpy array in a sqlalchemy database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to setup a database to store some processed arrays and I'm struggling to understand how to properly store and retrieve numpy arays into it.

The table is created using the following syntax:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class Velocities(Base):

    #declaring the tablename
    __tablename__ = 'velocities'

    #defining the columns
    #starting by the ID column
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)

   #defining a foreign key column
    obs_id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey('observations.id'))
    #obs = relationship(Observations)

    #the proper columns of this table
    vx = sql.Column(sql.LargeBinary, nullable = False)
    intEn = sql.Column(sql.Float, nullable = False)
```

Where the LargeBinary is using to store the arrays that usually have 500x1000 pxs. They are inserted in the database like this:

```
#here the actual data is led into the database
session = DBSession()
new_dave4vm = Dave4vm(vx = velocities['vx'],
                          intEn = int_En)
session.add(new_dave4vm)
session.commit()
```

I can normaly query and access the values of all the properties that are not arrays but if I want to retrieve the array values, like shown below:

```
a = []

for instance in session.query(Velocities).order_by(Velocities.id):
        a.append(instance.vx)
```

It seems that the arrays get compacted when inserted in the database so I can't just access the value or plot an image from what the query returns to me.

That being said I would like to ask how do I properly store and retrieve numpy arrays from a sqlalchemy database. Should I use some other tool/package to compact them first?

Thanks for your time!

---

Edit: There are some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940802/how-to-integrate-sqlalchemy-and-a-subclassed-numpy-ndarray-smoothly-and-in-a-pyt) that talk about numpy arrays and sqlalchemy. However I'm trying to find suggestions of how to perform this task and not focusing on a specific way.